# My Method is not defined

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to call a method from another method, I get the error "writeUserData" is not defined.
This is my code:

```
export default class RegisterScreen extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      verify: '',
      nickname: '',
    }

    this.handlePress = this.handlePress.bind(this)
    this.writeUserData = this.writeUserData.bind(this)
  }

  handlePress(navigation){
    if(this.state.password == this.state.verify){
      firebaseRef.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(function(newUser){
        const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
          index: 0,
          actions: [
            NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home'})
          ]
        })

        navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
        writeUserData(newUser.uid, this.nickname); //Problem here.
      }).catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
      });
    }else{
      //password not match, show error.
    }
  }

  writeUserData(mUID, mNickname){
    console.log("WRITE");
    firebaseRef.database().ref('users/' + mUID + '/').set({
      nickname: mNickname,
    });
  }
}
```

I'm trying to write the nickname and UID of a user after registration to the database.
I'm using Firebase and React Native.

I also tried to write this.writeUserData, but I get an error says "this.writeUserData" is not a function.

What Am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use arrow functions, it will change the reference of `this` to your class which will let you use your methods:

```
handlePress = (navigation) => { //this also makes it so you dont have to bind in constructor
    if(this.state.password == this.state.verify){
      firebaseRef.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((newUser) => { //arrow function here
        const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
          index: 0,
          actions: [
            NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home'})
          ]
        })

        navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
        this.writeUserData(newUser.uid, this.nickname); //Problem here.
      }).catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
      });
    }else{
      //password not match, show error.
    }
  }
```

Comment: Arrow functions are es6, you can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions